# Remove lines from text file, while other files are trying to access

Tags: c, fopen

I have a file which I've opened a reference to using fopen_s

Now I want to remove certain lines from the file.

Most recommendations are to copy the lines I want to a temp file, delete the original file and then write back the lines to a newly created file.

However, I have an additional problem that up to 20 other systems could be trying to access this file at the same time. They have been coded to wait until the file becomes available before adding/removing their data.

I am worried that as soon as I close the original file (to delete it) one of the other systems will nip in and edit that file locking it out to my original system.

Can anyone suggest a method that I can use in this particular scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rename the file (maybe using the Process/thread Id in the name), create your temp file in the same folder, delete the renamed file and rename the temp file back to the original name.

Comment: I see, so rename file first so effectively other process can't see it?

Comment: @user1853330 that's right -- better check the return value of rename to take care of two or more programs trying to rename at the same time

Comment: I'm checking response from rename and re-trying over 10 seconds then exiting function if !=0.

Comment: I'm also renaming back even if some other part of code causes an error otherwise other system will stop. - Thanks for suggestion.